# Understanding selections and looping in a divisor program

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, increment

My homework is asking me to use a defined range (by entering the highest number in the range) and a divisor input by the user to find all numbers in the range that are divisible by the divisor, without using mathematical or assignment operators except for ++, --, or = ( +, -, /, *, %, +=, %=, etc. are not allowed).

The program was extremely easy to write with math operators, but when I try writing it with only increment operators I get lost every time. I am extremely new to programming.

Below is the code I have so far, but it prints each number in the range (1 to max number) after the divisor (so if the divisor input by the user is 5 and the max number is 20, it will print every number 5-20), rather than only the numbers divisible by the divisor (5, 10, 15, 20).

```
    input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // input the ending number
    System.out.println("Enter the ending number: ");
    n = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the divisor: ");
    count = input.nextInt();
    variable = 0;
    System.out.println("Below are all the numbers that are evenly divisible by " + count + " from 1 up to " + n);

    while (count <= n){
        variable++; 
        if (variable == count){
            System.out.print(count + "  ");
            count++;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop your count that many times, 
Now below should work, for max number odd and even

```
 int temp = count;
    while(count<n)
    {

        for(int i=0; i<temp; i++)
        {
             variable++;

        }
        if(variable>n) break;
        else {
        count = variable;
        System.out.println(count);
        }

    }
```

Comment: This works, except I needed to change count <= n to count < n, so to make sure it doesn't include the number after the last one in the defined range. Thank you a million times over, you wouldn't believe how long I was stuck on this.

Comment: I'm sorry if I downvoted, I thought I upvoted. This is the first time I've used this site.

Comment: @BrandonBischoff No problem.